# Parse a multi-layered JSON from INSEE API

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm sending a request to an API. This API is [INSEE](https://api.insee.fr/catalogue/site/themes/wso2/subthemes/insee/pages/item-info.jag?name=Sirene&version=V3&provider=insee), it is the French official repositories of registered companies.

Here is my request:

```py
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'xxx'
}

params = (
    ('q', 'siren:530085802'),
    ('date', '2021-10-01'),
    ('champs', 'siret, denominationUniteLegale, codePostalEtablissement, libelleCommuneEtablissement, denominationUsuelleEtablissement'),
    ('debut', 1)
    # ('nombre', 1)
)

response = requests.get('https://api.insee.fr/entreprises/sirene/V3/siret', headers=headers, params=params)
```

For this example, I'm requesting Facebook's legal entity by its number : `siren:530085802` (this is *Open Data*, nothing here is confidential).

Now I get a response:

```
reponse.text
```

This :

```json
'{"header":{"statut":200,"message":"OK","total":3,"debut":1,"nombre":2},"etablissements":[{"siret":"53008580200011","uniteLegale":{"denominationUniteLegale":"FACEBOOK FRANCE"},"adresseEtablissement":{"codePostalEtablissement":"75116","libelleCommuneEtablissement":"PARIS 16"},"periodesEtablissement":[{"dateFin":null,"dateDebut":"2012-06-14","denominationUsuelleEtablissement":null},{"dateFin":"2012-06-13","dateDebut":"2011-02-17","denominationUsuelleEtablissement":null},{"dateFin":"2011-02-16","dateDebut":"2011-01-01","denominationUsuelleEtablissement":null}]},{"siret":"53008580200037","uniteLegale":{"denominationUniteLegale":"FACEBOOK FRANCE"},"adresseEtablissement":{"codePostalEtablissement":"75002","libelleCommuneEtablissement":"PARIS 2"},"periodesEtablissement":[{"dateFin":null,"dateDebut":"2018-06-26","denominationUsuelleEtablissement":null},{"dateFin":"2018-06-25","dateDebut":"2016-04-18","denominationUsuelleEtablissement":null}]}]}'
```

As per the official documentation, there are multiple layers :

- Legal entity : Identified by a `siren`
- Establishment : Identified by a `siret` – which is the SIREN + 5 characters. Basically here I'm getting a list of establishments, since I'm requesting only one SIREN
- Periods : Which is archived/change tracking of several attributes. With a `dateDebut` (starting date) and a `dateFin` (end date) and attributes, among which the `denominationUsuelleEtablissement` I'd like to have the current values.

Despite putting a date in my request, the API responded with several periods, not only the one that includes the date I'm providing. Hence adding a layer.

**What I'm trying to do is to flatten the response and convert it to a dataframe for easier use.**

What I've done is the following. Using `json.normalize`:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

contenuReponse = json.loads(response.text)
etablissements = contenuReponse['etablissements']
 
df = pd.json_normalize(etablissements)
df
```

I get this:

|  | siret | periodesEtablissements | uniteLegale.denominationUniteLegale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 53008580200011 | [{'dateFin': None, 'dateDebut': '2012-06-14', ... | FACEBOOK FRANCE |
| 1 | 53008580200037 | [{'dateFin': None, 'dateDebut': '2018-06-26', ... | FACEBOOK FRANCE |

`json_normalize` *ignores* the layer below `periodesEtablissement`.

Is there a way to flatten successfully the whole response. Or, use only the `periodesEtablissement` relevant to my request. Meaning the one with no `dateFin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using this function:

```
def flatten_nested_json_df(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    
    s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    
    while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
        new_columns = []

        for col in dict_columns:
            horiz_exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
            horiz_exploded.index = df.index
            df = pd.concat([df, horiz_exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
            new_columns.extend(horiz_exploded.columns) # inplace

        for col in list_columns:
            print(f"exploding: {col}")
            df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
            new_columns.append(col)

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
        list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
        dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    return df
```

and do this:

```
flatten_nested_json_df(df)
```

which gives:

```
  index           siret uniteLegale.denominationUniteLegale  \
0      0  53008580200011                     FACEBOOK FRANCE   
0      0  53008580200011                     FACEBOOK FRANCE   
0      0  53008580200011                     FACEBOOK FRANCE   
1      1  53008580200037                     FACEBOOK FRANCE   
1      1  53008580200037                     FACEBOOK FRANCE   

  adresseEtablissement.codePostalEtablissement  \
0                                        75116   
0                                        75116   
0                                        75116   
1                                        75002   
1                                        75002   

  adresseEtablissement.libelleCommuneEtablissement  \
0                                         PARIS 16   
0                                         PARIS 16   
0                                         PARIS 16   
1                                          PARIS 2   
1                                          PARIS 2   

  periodesEtablissement.dateFin periodesEtablissement.dateDebut  \
0                          None                      2012-06-14   
0                    2012-06-13                      2011-02-17   
0                    2011-02-16                      2011-01-01   
1                          None                      2018-06-26   
1                    2018-06-25                      2016-04-18   

  periodesEtablissement.denominationUsuelleEtablissement  
0                                               None      
0                                               None      
0                                               None      
1                                               None      
1                                               None
```

Comment: I came accross this function or a similar one but I wasn't able to get a proper result.

The function and a .loc to remove some lines did the trick.

Comment: Is this universal for flattening nested JSONs?

Comment: Yes it is. I haven't yet come across a well structured json on which it didn't work.